# Multiple requests in one TTURLRequestModel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I was using the facebook example code of three20 as a basis for a project, and I want to have two url requests in my TTURLRequestModel class, so that I will only use one TTListDataSource to render my objects..

For example, a url request for the post details...
and another url request for all the comments of the post..

Answer (score 1):

You need to open up TT code and make your own modifications. I don't think it's supported.
One solution I can think of is that you create two models and when model finishes you add cellItems in your datasource.